# How to call function using Nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, nunjucks

I want to call the jQuery function in HTML using Nunjucks, but it's giving me an error. I have imported the JS file into the HTML file.

> Error: Unable to call 'fooName', which is undefined or falsey

Does anyone know why I can't call the function? Here is my code example:

```html
<a class="btn" onclick="{{fooName(test)}}" href="#">Click me!</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const fooName = (name) => {
    console.log(`${this.name}`)
  };
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with nunjucks, however you're defining the `fooName` function *inside* the document.ready event handler. As such, it's out of scope of an `onclick` attribute, as functions this invokes must be globally accessible. To fix this you need to either move the `fooName()` function *outside* of document.ready, or remove the `onclick` attribute and bind the event handler using jQuery as well. I'd suggest the latter is the better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My situation was a bit different but still I think it works in this case too

The idea is to add a function to the global window object

Within the view render method that passes variables to nunjucks I added this function

```
var self = this;

window.onClick = function (id) {
 // self.fetchData(id);
 // Do something
}
```

and within nunjucks

```
<a class="btn" onclick="window.onClick({{item.id}})">Click me!</a>
```

it works perfectly.